# Synergy wont be installed

Tags: installation, uninstall, synergy

Hello I'm new to linux and all that so I might have lots of questions.

If possible it would be cool to be directed to a site where all kinds of commands all the good things to know about linux and ubuntu is explained in a good way.

Heres my question.

when I'm trying to install synergy, it says:
"dpkg: fejl under behandling af synergy-1.4.15-Linux-i686.deb (--install):
 synergy:i386 1.4.15 (Multi-Arch: no) is not co-installable with synergy:amd64 1.3.8-1ubuntu1 (Multi-Arch: no) which is currently installed
Der opstod fejl under behandlingen: 
 synergy-1.4.15-Linux-i686.deb

All help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's telling you that you already have another version installed. Try this commands:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge synergy

sudo dpkg -i synergy-1.4.15-Linux-i686.deb
```

This will uninstall the package from the ppa and install the one you downloaded locally.